# Messages concerning MFC-CTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, tree, mfc, message

At the moment we have created some classes which are derived from `CTreeCtrl`. There are problems with `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` that is not sent at all.

By trial and error we found out that we had to use the Unicode version of `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING`. Otherwise the callback function is not invoked.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    ...
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_ITEMEXPANDINGW, OnExpand)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This is somehow curious because we are not in an Unicode application at all and on other positions of the program we have used `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` which leads to the ANSI version `TVN_ITEMEXPANDINGA`. This is defined in `CommCtrl.h`

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define TVN_SELCHANGING         TVN_SELCHANGINGW
#define TVN_SELCHANGED          TVN_SELCHANGEDW
#define TVN_GETDISPINFO         TVN_GETDISPINFOW
#define TVN_SETDISPINFO         TVN_SETDISPINFOW
#define TVN_ITEMEXPANDING       TVN_ITEMEXPANDINGW
#define TVN_ITEMEXPANDED        TVN_ITEMEXPANDEDW
#define TVN_BEGINDRAG           TVN_BEGINDRAGW
#define TVN_BEGINRDRAG          TVN_BEGINRDRAGW
#define TVN_DELETEITEM          TVN_DELETEITEMW
#define TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT      TVN_BEGINLABELEDITW
#define TVN_ENDLABELEDIT        TVN_ENDLABELEDITW
#else
#define TVN_SELCHANGING         TVN_SELCHANGINGA
#define TVN_SELCHANGED          TVN_SELCHANGEDA
#define TVN_GETDISPINFO         TVN_GETDISPINFOA
#define TVN_SETDISPINFO         TVN_SETDISPINFOA
#define TVN_ITEMEXPANDING       TVN_ITEMEXPANDINGA
#define TVN_ITEMEXPANDED        TVN_ITEMEXPANDEDA
#define TVN_BEGINDRAG           TVN_BEGINDRAGA
#define TVN_BEGINRDRAG          TVN_BEGINRDRAGA
#define TVN_DELETEITEM          TVN_DELETEITEMA
#define TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT      TVN_BEGINLABELEDITA
#define TVN_ENDLABELEDIT        TVN_ENDLABELEDITA
#endif
```

Does someone have a clue why `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` is needed both in the Unicode and ANSI Version in the same program? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How was the tree control (not the MFC class created) ?  Was it created to be a  Unicode control ?

Comment: @RichardCritten You cannot *"create"* a window class instance to be Unicode or ANSI. That decision is made when the control author calls `RegisterClassExA` or `RegisterClassExW`. That's probably a red herring, and the core issue is more likely to do with the parent window/window class/parent window class registration.

Comment: You can check whether a window is Unicode by calling the `IsWindowUnicode()` function. MFC creates a `CTreeCtrl` window using the `WC_TREEVIEW` window class name (both the multibyte and wide strings are the same), So it depends on the version of MFC you are actually using (project and compiler settings etc).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I just went about explaining, that creating an instance of a window class doesn't determine the character set used by a window. That decision isn't up to the call to `CreateWindowEx[W|A]`. Please try creating an MFC project where `IsWindowUnicode()` returns `FALSE` for *any* window class instance other than those *you* registered. Best of luck.

Comment: @IInspectable, I didn't try to explain what went wrong (more specifically I didn't mention `CreateWindow()` at all) , and I think MFC may call either version, depending on the project settings. The point here is that the window is apparently Unicode (and the `IsWindowUnicode()` call can tell this with certainty), while the OP expected a multibyte one.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Try to create me a `WC_TREEVIEW[A|W]` control, by **any** means, where `IsWindowUnicode()` would return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Just made a test-app to check the above: MFC Dialog Application, MFC in a DLL, 64-bit, MBCS, subclassed Tree-View control (CTreeCtrl-derived). It worked at once and behaved **exactly** as expected: if compiled with the MBCS option the control-class receives the (reflected) ANSI `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` notification, otherwise the Unicode one.

Also, the `IsWindowUnicode()` function returns `FALSE` if the project was built with the MBCS option. Querying the Unicode Format setting for the control's content (`TVM_GETUNICODEFORMAT`) returns consistent results as well.

Also found that sending the `TVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT` message can alter the above behavior. For example, a MBCS tree-view control (`IsWindowUnicode()` returns `FALSE`) that has received the `TVM_SETUNICODEFORMAT` message with `wParam` set to `1` (changed to Unicode) will be receiving the Unicode notification (`TVN_ITEMEXPANDINGW`).

Therefore there must be something wrong with your project or compiler settings, or your class code. Win32 was found to fully support both MBCS and Unicode Tree-View controls, and work really well. Uploading a MRE could help maybe.